# How to properly draw Use case diagrams with access restrictions?

Tags: uml, actor, analysis, diagram

The system has 3 types of users : system admin, company user and supplier user. One of the system functionalities is to manage a list of unit costs for some actions. I am trying to draw a UML use case of this specific functionality but I don't really know if I am doing it properly.
Only the system admin and the company user can access this functionality, is it right to specify that like in the picture below?
Is there something wrong or mistake in this use case?

[image]

Comment: Either connect user with the bubble (and none of the others) or leave it away completely. Else that's ok.

Comment: So User if it exists as parent, it should be connected to a bubble but not left without an association ? Is it some kind of rule to not leave parent without an association?

Comment: Having a general user without connecting it to a bubble is meaningless. Each actor needs to have at least one bubble connected. If you connect them all three in your case there's redundancy which also is to be avoided.

Comment: @qwerty_so I fully agree that having an actor not connected to any use-cas is not super-useful. It only provides information about the context that could be relevant only for other diagrams in the same model). But strictly speaking, is there something in the specs that say that actors MUST be connected to at least one use case (and if there’s such a rule is the obligation per diagram or or the whole model) ?

Comment: My point was to say that those two actors are child of User but at the same time I wanted to specify access restriction to the use case since there is Supplier User as well child of User which is used in other use case diagram. Connecting User to the bubble goes against my point as I don't want anyone to think that Supplier User can access that use case as well. So, I removed User and kept others connected to the bubble.